# dplyr mean group on Long Format Data

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I have trouble figuring out how I can compute a simple mean with `dplyr` on Long Format data.

My data look like this :

```
   hldid   idno sex diary age
1   1294 1294_1   2     1  39
2   1294 1294_1   2     2  39
3   1294 1294_2   1     1  43
4   1294 1294_2   1     2  43
...
```

With 4 variables : `hldid idno sex diary age` 
`idno` is the **personal identifier** but not the **unique key**.

Each individual is repeated **2** times, one for each `diary` filled.

What I would like is to simply compute the `age` mean by `sex`.

Could you help me out ?

I tried something like :

```
 dta %>% 
   group_by(sex) %>%
   mutate( ng = n_distinct(idno)) %>%
   group_by(age, add=TRUE) %>%
   summarise(mean = n()/ng[1] )
```

But it does not work.

The data :

```
dta = structure(list(hldid = c(1294, 1294, 1294, 1294, 1352, 1352, 
1352, 1352, 3741, 3741, 3741, 3741, 3809, 3809, 3809, 3809, 4037, 
4037, 4037, 4037), idno = c("1294_1", "1294_1", "1294_2", "1294_2", 
"1352_1", "1352_1", "1352_2", "1352_2", "3741_1", "3741_1", "3741_2", 
"3741_2", "3809_1", "3809_1", "3809_2", "3809_2", "4037_1", "4037_1", 
"4037_2", "4037_2"), sex = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), diary = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
 2L, 1L, 2L), age = c(39L, 39L, 43L, 43L, 31L, 31L, 37L, 37L, 
33L, 33L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 34L, 37L, 37L, 41L, 41L, 32L, 32L)), .Names = c("hldid", 
"idno", "sex", "diary", "age"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), vars = list(hldid), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
0:3, 4:7, 8:11, 12:15, 16:19), group_sizes = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(hldid = c(1294, 
1352, 3741, 3809, 4037)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .Names = "hldid", vars = list(hldid)))
```

**quick update**

Maybe this does not apply for this example, 
but this kind of issues I have in mind is the following :

Imagine we have data like this : 
3 women and 2 men, and a dummy `act` variable.

If we do and not taking into account the Long format computing the `mean`, we will have problems.

```
aggregate(act ~ sex, FUN = mean, data = dtaTime)
```

What we should do is this :

```
aggregate(act ~ sex, FUN = sum, data = dtaTime)
6 / 2 # men 
10 / 3 # women
```

Data

```
dtaTime = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), act = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "sex", 
"act"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: The data at the end cannot be read in because it has some `vars = list(hldid)` thing in it and we do not have `hldid`

Comment: You are making it too complicated, `dta %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(meanage = mean(age))` should give you the mean age by sex.

Comment: I know that doing this gives the correct results by I was wondering because we do not specify the `n_distinct` identifiers if it could cause issues. Because it does in general when you compute mean on long format data.

Comment: @Jaap That looks like a good answer. And if they are facing people (`idno`s) with differing numbers of `diary` entries (hopefully with `age` being constant for each `idno`), you could put a `distinct(idno)` at the front.

Comment: @Frank - you mean like : `dta %>% distinct(idno) %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(meanage = mean(age))` ? I just want to be sure taking into account the repeated identifiers

Comment: @giacomoV I'm not sure what you mean. What I meant was: if you want to give more weight to someone because they have more diary entries, then Jaap's version (without `distinct`) works, if you want the more standard weighting (with each person equally weighted), you can use `distinct`.

Comment: If every id is repeated _exactly_ twice in the data, you don't need `distinct`. The other option would be to use two summarise's (but shouldn't be necessary if your description is precise) e.g. `dta %>% group_by(sex, idno) %>% summarise(age = mean(age, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% summarise(mean_age = mean(age))` (you lose the second grouping variable "idno" after the first summarise)

Comment: @giacomoV I'd suggest posting a new question where you elaborate on (1) the meaning of "not taking into account the Long format" and (2) what you mean by mean, which seems to differ from normal use. A variety of already-provided solutions produce desired output for your new example data, like `dtaTime %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(sum(act)/n_distinct(id))`

Comment: ok sure you are right

Comment: Your updated example indicates you might be looking for `dtaTime %>% group_by(sex, id) %>% summarise(act = sum(act)) %>% summarise(mean_act = mean(act))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making it too complicated,

```
dta %>% 
   group_by(sex) %>% 
   summarise(meanage = mean(age))
```

should give you the mean age by sex.

A base R alternative:

```
aggregate(age ~ sex, dta, mean)
```

A `data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)[, .(meanage = mean(age)), by = sex]
```

Comment: I made a quick update explaining what I have in mind. But maybe this does not apply to the question I asked and if not I would be interested to know why in one case it's simple and in another it is not. Thanks guys.